# how to check if multiple similarly named variables are missing in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm working with data connected to tourism and traveling. In my data set variables connected to a person's first voyage is prefixed by R1_, variables connected to the second with R2_ and so forth up to R3_.

What I want to do is to delete the observation if all variable values R1 through R3 are missing.

How do I make this happen? Do I have to write out the names of all 500+ variables manually?

Variables R1 through R3 can be both both character and numeric

I try just writing:

```
Data dataset;
set dataset2;
if missing(R1_:) and missing(R2_:) and missing(R3_:) then delete;
run;
```

But I just get the following error message:

```
28         Data dataset;
29         set dataset2;
30         if missing(R1_:) and missing(R2_:) and missing(R3_:) then delete;
                         _
                         388
                         200
                         76
ERROR 388-185: Expecting an arithmetic operator.

ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to write out the names of all 500+ variables manually?

Of course not.
You are missing the [`OF`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lrcon/n1t04bwpt1jkadn1a5mk35we2yif.htm) operator which enables you to specify SAS variable lists or SAS arrays as arguments to functions.
You also need to use the [`CMISS()`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_033/lefunctionsref/p1tth4ltf640din1ey86ubo2lky2.htm) function instead. The [`MISSING()`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/ds2ref/p0lok2xwfrbw8ln1n9bnbci2euuq.htm) function can have only one argument.

```
data want;
set have;
if cmiss(of R1_:) and cmiss(of R2_:) and cmiss(of R3_:) then delete;
run;
```

---

```
data have;
infile datalines delimiter='|' missover;
input R1_1 $ R1_2 $ R2_1 :$9. R2_2 $ R3_1 $ R3_2 $;
cards;
Bangkok|Zurich|Paris|Zurich|Paris|Zurich
Geneva|Zurich|Frankfurt||Paris|Zurich
|||||
London| |Zurich|Lisbon|Paris|Zurich
;

data want;
set have;
if cmiss(of R1_:) and cmiss(of R2_:) and cmiss(of R3_:) then delete;
run;
```

```
+---------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+
|  R1_1   |  R1_2  |   R2_1    |  R2_2  |  R3_1  |  R3_2  |
+---------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+
| Bangkok | Zurich | Paris     | Zurich | Paris  | Zurich |
| Geneva  | Zurich | Frankfurt | Paris  | Zurich |        |
| London  |        | Zurich    | Lisbon | Paris  | Zurich |
+---------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: I don't know, now it says my missing function call has to many arguments?

Comment: I edited my post. Can you try again?

Answer (score 0):

The following method of adressing columns is not absolutely flexible but can be useful:

```
Data dataset;
  length R1_1-R1_10 8;
  length R2_A R2_B R2_C 8;

  if missing(R1_1-R1_10) then put "yes 1";
  if missing(R2_A-R2_C) then put "yes 2";
run;
```

Log:

```
NOTE: Variable R1_1 is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable R1_2 is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable R1_3 is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable R1_4 is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable R1_5 is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable R1_6 is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable R1_7 is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable R1_8 is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable R1_9 is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable R1_10 is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable R2_A is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable R2_B is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable R2_C is uninitialized.
yes 1
yes 2
```

Comment: I don't think this works like you think it does.  You are testing different R1_1 minus R1_10.  Not variables R1_1 R1_2 ... R1_10 is all missing.